# Swift drag subview to delete on certain position

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, subview

I am trying to figure out a way to drag and delete a subview when reaches at a certain position. What i have so far is a view controller on which i add several subviews. My subview classes are rotatable and resizable and i can move them on the view controller. Let say that i want to move a subview on top center of my view controller and delete it. How my parent view controller know the position of the subview and perform the deletion?
Another issue is that all the subviews are generated from the same custom class. How should i define which subview is the one that should be deleted?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/antonio081014/TouchDemo) out, this is the WWDC demo I duplicated, this might help you.

Comment: Thank you that is really helpful. I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UIPanGestureRecognizer to move the views and [CGRect.intersects](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgrect/1454747-intersects) to see if the new position takes you into the delete zone (use instead [contains](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgrect/1454186-contains) if you want to require that you are completely inside the delete zone):

```
    @IBAction func pan(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        centerXConstraint.constant += translation.x
        centerYConstraint.constant += translation.y
        viewToMove.offset.x += translation.x
        viewToMove.offset.y += translation.y
        if viewToMove.frame.intersects(deletionRect) {
            //Delete logic here
        } else {
            viewToMove.setNeedsDisplay()
            recognizer.setTranslation(.zero, in: self.view)
        }

    }
```

If you have multiple views you can use either  UIView.tag or a Set to figure out which view is which.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This gesture should be implemented on the subview or the controller. Because i use a UIPanGestureRecognizer on my subview class.

Comment: Actually I would still implement it on the viewController and use an array of views.  in that case you put the pan gesture recognizer on the main view and just check the array when the gesture recognized begins views.first {$0.frame.contains(point)} to get the view that was first touched.  This way you don't need a subclass and a protocol.